# Sitecore SxA Composite Layout not adding custom css and js

Tags: sxa

We have created a custom Accordion Module. Therefore, we also changed the Accordion MVC Layout.cshtml for Accordion Items. But our custom theme doesn't appear in the head nor does the js show up. What did we miss?

Comment: What did you do? (before we can answer what you might be missing, we need more info about what you have been doing)

Comment: I've duplicated the Accordion MVC Layout. On the Accordion Item on the Standard Values I've changed the Layout to my copied Layout.

Comment: @NadineLendzian Did you modified the layout *.cshtml file? Can you show me it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any additional pieces of information from your side (as it was suggested in the comments) so I will write what I think you might be missing.

You wrote that you have a custom `AccordionMvcLayout.cshtml`. If you will take a look inside of that file, you will notice that on the top there is something like:

```
@{
    Layout = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("XA.Feature.Composites.CompositeComponentLayoutPath", "Composite Component Layout.cshtml");
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit accordion item";
}
```

This view is using its own layout which is most cases (if not changed) is `Composite Component Layout.cshtml`. Go there and you will find the following lines in that file:

```
@{
    AssetLinks assetLinks = AssetLinksGenerator.GenerateLinks(new CompositeThemesProvider());
}

...

@foreach (string style in assetLinks.Styles)
{
    @Html.Raw(style)
}

...

@{
    foreach (string script in assetLinks.Scripts)
    {
        @Html.Raw(script)
    }
    ...
}
```

This code is responsible for rendering CSS and JS link. So double check if you custom layout have `Layout = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("XA.Feature.Composites.CompositeComponentLayoutPath", "Composite Component Layout.cshtml");` just like the original one.

Comment: I've checked my AccordionMvcLayout.cshtml and it does have the code you mentioned:
@{
    Layout = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("XA.Feature.Composites.CompositeComponentLayoutPath", "Composite Component Layout.cshtml");
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit accordion item";
}